# TCA selectCheckBox - Output in fluid template

Tags: fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I use in TCA

```
        'uebersetzungen' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:maschinen/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_maschinen_domain_model_maschine.uebersetzungen',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'items' => [
                ['6:1', 1],
                ['8:1', 2],
                ['11:1', 3],
                ['14:1', 4],
            ],
            'size' => 4,
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'eval' => ''
        ],
    ],
```

to get the output in fluid template with

```
        <f:switch expression="{maschine.uebersetzungen}">
            <f:case value="1">6:1</f:case>
            <f:case value="2">8:1</f:case>
            <f:case value="3">11:1</f:case>
            <f:case value="4">14:1</f:case>
        </f:switch>
```

Now I want to change the renderType to

```
'renderType' => 'selectSingleBox'
```

but I have no idea how to get the several values.

I read [TYPO3 TCA type select in FLUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561593/typo3-tca-type-select-in-fluid/35562339#35562339)
but I'm not sure whether it's the same problem because I have a different syntax in TCA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Paul Beck I found an answer for my problem.

I can use the solution posted here: [TYPO3 TCA type select in FLUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561593/typo3-tca-type-select-in-fluid/35562339#35562339)

But I had to change the line

```
protected $featuresDecoded;
```

to

```
protected $featuresDecoded = [];
```

Comment: That's a solution for PHP-5.3 +. For being compatible with older PHP-versions (if anyone needs to be compatible ...) the solution would be `protected $featuresDecoded = array();`